# KafkaStreams writing to disk while reading from a topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've been investigating disk writes on a Kafka Streams application, and I reduced the topology to a bare minimum, that is:

```
KStream<String, JsonElement> stream = builder.stream("input-topic");
```

Yet on `docker stats` I can observe that my application keeps writing something to disk. I've checked the container and I can't see any suspicious file handles.

If I comment the aforementioned line, this issue disappears, so I came to a conclusion that just reading from a topic writes *something* on disk, but I can't guess what and why.

In addition, I've noticed it is strictly related to commit interval setting; increasing it makes the writes less frequent. Each time about 130kB of data is being written.

Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kafka Streams writes checkpoint files to local disk. Those checkpoint files are actually just used for stateful tasks, but are create even if there is no stateful operation (for this case, the checkpoint file will be almost empty).

It's a known issue and fixed in upcoming 1.1 release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6499

Comment: Thanks, that explains it, I've found the .checkpoint files. Since my input topic has 32 partitions and my block size is 4kB, writing all of them indeed matches the disk IO I was seeing (128kB per batch).